# Windows linux subsystem button not working as expected

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just fresh installed windows on my machine and added the linux subsystem (ubuntu for now..) but I am experiencing a strange behavior when using it. The letter `i` is not working. Actually it even produce the sound of the error when pressed ( the classic ding ). The button has absolute no problem as it works just fine when in windows. It works in command line ( windows ) but it also works in linux subsystem when I open nano and start typing. The problem is only in the bash. ( If I type a command in nano

```
#!/bin/bash 
mkdir iiii
```

and execute the script it will run as expected.

So the only conclusion I can come up with is there is a shortcut on the button `i` which i cannot find and is not working ( thus creating the error sound ).

Any ideas how can i disable this shortcut so i will be able to type "i" on my console ( which apparently I use more than expected.. and noticed due to the errors! )

Thank you in advance.

**Edit** 
Even pasting a word containing `i` will skip writting it ( tried to paste `history` got `hstory` + beep )

Comment: I'm suspecting bash could be receiving a ctrl-i (same as tab, triggers autocompletion). Could you check in a context where auto-completion would be possible whether it still beeps and does nothing or it autocompletes?

Comment: @Aaron I created a folder containing i (lets call it shine ) , typed sh + tab for autocomplete and it completes without the beep been played.

Comment: I meant to ask you to type `sh` + i and see if it autocompletes. If it does, that means that when you press i, bash actually receives a ctrl-i

Comment: @Aaron Ok tried it just now. It doesn't add the `i` and the beep keeps playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got the solution on my own. Apparently including `/etc/inputrc` on my profile ( inside my .inputrc ) was creating the problem and its not ubuntu specific. Tested on subsystem and on actual debian installation and it does the same.! So just removed the include and it works